# Controller class in my Web project

Tags: c#

I create a Web project in C# in Visual Studio 2013.
And it auto-generates 2 Controller classes for me.

One of Controller classes has this Get method() which will be invoked when I type  `http://localhost/myapplication/api/value/1` in my browser.

My question is why a new Controller class is being constructed everytime I refresh my browser to hit 
`http://localhost/myapplication/api/value/1` for refreshing?

What if I want to some initialization in my web application, where should I put that logic?
I need to init some data structures when my web app starts and the Controller classes need to access those data structures.

Right now, I put the logic in the Controller constructor, which does not work because that is being called every time I have a HTTP request to the web app.

Comment: Is this asp.net web api? How about put it in `Application_Start` ?

Comment: I create a Web Visual C# project. I am not sure if it is 'asp.net'. It creates Controller classes for me in C#.